# QGIS startup error (out of range pointer)

Tags: qgis, installation

I downloaded QGIS (for Windows) and installed the software. However, when I start QGIS, I get an error message:

```
"The Instruction at 0x04c20d55 referenced memory at 0xffffffff. The memory could not be read."
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem??

Comment: Please let us know your system and OS Details.I think its might RAM problem..IF possible remove qgis---reboot machine and reinstall software also check system requirement

Comment: According to the http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=121904 link it might DLL file problem and Update the windows.

Comment: It just might be a dll that installs with Qgis, not a standard Windows dll.

Answer (score 1):

We have a standalone installer for Windows and the OSGeo4W installer. Which one have you used? Try the other one to see if its getting better.

For the standalone installer, install into a path with no blanks, as this causes some problems.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried the OSGeo4W installer. This time now error messages. Everthing works fine! Regards, Tim